# If an unhandled exception occurs, is App.OnSuspending still called?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Title says it all. Basically, in a Windows 8 Store App, if an unhandled exception occurs then will the OnSuspending event be called? I've found this is practically impossible to debug with any amount of certainty

Comment: This ought to be done the Socratic way.  An app stores its state in the suspend event handler so it can cleanly restart when it happens to get terminated.  Would you like WinRT to call your suspend event handler when your program state is completely corrupted?   Perhaps that's obvious.  Have you considered what happens when the exception occurs on a worker thread, just as your suspend handler is running?

Comment: @HansPassant I meant it was impossible to debug because the only way you can even get a breakpoint on the Suspend event is to explicitly suspend the program from Visual Studio. I wasn't sure if unhandled skips straight to terminated or what.. but apparently it does go straight to terminated

Answer (score 0):

No it is not called. :(

I found out this when developing with the new MediaCapture APIs.  If you don't clean up resources (e.g. stop recording/preview) the phone becomes unstable and freezes the OS when trying to use the camera the next time.  The recommendation is to use the suspending event to clean up the resources, therefore thats what I did.  But my phone (device not emulator) would become unstable if I encountered an unhandled exception, therefore the cleanup method was not called.  This leads me to believe that on unhandled exception, suspending is not called.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/Dn642092(v=win.10)#cleaning_up_mediacapture_resources_properly

I'd recommend doing what berXpert suggested.  Setting handled to be true doing your action then exiting out.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to call something after unhandled happens, you could attach to the unhandledexception event at the App object:

```
public App()
{
    ...
    this.UnhandledException += (s,e) => { 
            e.Handled = true; 
            this.DoSomethingWithTheError; 
            this.Exit(); 
    };
}
```

It will exit the app any way.

Comment: sorry I downvoted before realizing you had something unique here.  At first I didn't see DoSomethingWithTheError / Exit.  My bad.  But a way to improve your answer would be to write out what is unique and explain that instead of say 'handle the unhandled event'